# How to convert time 06D 21H 03M to total minutes in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am running `net session` to extract user Idle time, In some rows the idle time is coming in the format `06D 21H 03M` i.e `xD yH zM`. I want to calculate total minutes.

Though I can try using split and match but it will be like running like mulitple loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782365(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
[timespan]::ParseExact("06D 21H 03M", "dd\D\ h\H\ mm\M", $null).totalminutes
```

Here it gives 9903.

Be sure to try catch the expression, because it's somehow sensible to the format.

---

Edited :

- Works fine under PowerShell 5.0 (Windows 10).
- Works fine under PowerShell 4.0 (Windows 7 + W2K12 Server).
- No longer able to test it under PowerShell 3.0.
- Don't works under PowerShell version 2.0.

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.TimeSpan] doesn't contain a method named 'ParseExact'.

Comment: Ok looks like some version issue becuase it's working fine on another version and not on 2.0. Thank you.

Comment: In PowerShell 2.0 you can use Regex matches and inside the TimeSpan Constuctor.